# Setting StartDate for calendar from textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, calendar

By default the calendar tool always opens to the current date when first clicked. Any clicks after that, opens it to the date previously clicked.

Is there a way to have the initial click open on a date that depends on a textbox?

Say for example: Upon loading the page, a textBox already has the date 2011/05/15. When the user clicks the calendar image button to open the calendar, the year, month and day are already set to 2011/05/15.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadGV();
    }
}

protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (Calendar1.Visible)
    {
        txtTime.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Calendar1.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Calendar1.Visible = true;
        Calendar1.Attributes.Add("style", "BACKGROUND: white; POSITION: absolute");
        Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(txtTime.Text);
    }
}

protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["TIME"] = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    txtTime.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Calendar1.Visible = false;
}

protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any particular reason you don't just drop in a plane jane textbox, and set it to as date?

Like this:

```
    <h4>Enter Date</h4>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date">
    </asp:TextBox>
```

and thus we get this:

[image]

so, with above, the text box is still the text box, but also is the datepicker.

## Edit#2: Select date on one page, pass to next page.

Ok, so we going to select a date on one page. Jump to next page.

On next page, we have a text box to select the date (or pass from previous page).

Also, when we update/change this text box, we want to re-load the grid data based on this text box.

So, first page we have this:

Text box, and button to jump to next page

```
        <h4>Select date</h4>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
            TextMode="date"
            >
        </asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit"
            cssClass="btn" OnClick="Button1_Click1"/>
```

our button click code for above button is this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["MyDate"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
    }
```

We now jump to page 2, and on first load (!IsPostback), then we have this code:

A date box above the grid (to filter),
And gridview.

```
       <lable style="font-size:large">Bookings for</lable>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
            textmode="Date" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" Font-Size="Large"
            ></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="40%" >

        </asp:GridView>
```

and the code behind is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = (string)Session["MyDate"];
            if (TextBox1.Text == "")
                TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT * FROM vBookings WHERE @From = cast(FromDate as date)
            ORDER BY FromDate";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@From", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TextBox1.Text;
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

the result looks like this:

[image]

So, I only have/need one text box. and I set autopostback = true.

So, the code for that text box is thus:

```
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

So, whatever value you shove into that text box should persit, should survice any post-back on that page, and it should retain its value.

Of course, you cannot build a working asp.net page UNLESS your setup code for that page is in that ALL VERY important !IsPostBack code stub.

The last 200+ web pages I build ALL HAVE that !IsPostBack stub, and you cannot really quite build a working web page unless you include that code stub.

if you do not check if this is REALLY the first page load, then all of your setup code for the page will run again and again - overwriting any changes you might make to such pages.

the above code - tested and works just fine.

So, you should not have any issues setting the value of the text box on that current page, or even passing a value for the text box from the previous page.

However, you do need to ensure that you don't re-set the text box value on each page load - and hence the !IsPostBack stub.

Comment: Using a textbox with `textmode=date` still produces the same issue. Upon opening the calendar, it shows the current month/day and the not the date located in the other textbox.

Comment: To shove in a date into a text box, and one that has textmode = date, then you should be able to. But then again on the other hand, why not just have that first text box set with textmode = date, and then  you don't have to transfer some value between the two text boxes? And if they are both textmode = date, then code again to transfer the value to the 2nd text box should work. So, it not clear the process (or requirement) to transfer the value from one text to the other - but with date mode you can and should be able to freely transfer the value between the boxes - either direction

Comment: In page one the user selects a date and enters their username. When they submit, they are taken to page 2 (the one with the calendar) which loads a gridview depending on the username and date selected. The user can then change the date with the calendar to change the contents of the gridview. The calendar is linked to a textbox for display purpuses. I have tried using textboxt with `textmode=date`  but the dropdown calendar from there still shows today's month/date and not the date from the previous page. Even with `textBox1.Text = Session["TIME"].toString():`

Comment: When the 2nd page loaded did you set the `txtTime.Text` in `!isPostBack`

Comment: see my new edit - I post a working sample of passing a value from previous page, and how my code loads the grid based on the setting of the text box. Once on this 2nd page, you are 100% free to change the date from text box, and the grid will update again since I have autopostback = true, and the text changed code stub.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Everything thing seems to work well, however for whatever reason, my textbox is still showing the date in 'MM-dd-yyyy' format. I've included the line of `TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` so I don't know what could be causing this?

Comment: Yes, in theory, you need and want to match the region settings. So, yes you do need to match up the date format to what your default is (this actaully is your computer regional settings). I should in fact post code that works without using a hard coded date format  setting. But, if your date picker is using that MM-dd-yyyy, then you need to use that format when stuffing the string into that text box as I did. So, for now, just match up the format you see in the textbox  with textmode = date - that tells you your current settings.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `else` part you can set the `date`

```
if (Calendar1.Visible)
{
    Calendar1.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    Calendar1.Visible = true;
    Calendar1.Attributes.Add("style", "BACKGROUND: white; POSITION: absolute");
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTime.Text))
    {
        Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(txtTime.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful because this can cause a `FormatException` if the `txtTime.Text` is not a valid datetime format. Use `DateTime.TryParse()` instead.

Comment: `txtTime.Text` and `Calendar1` date format is sync, that's why I don't use **TryParse**. But yes it's a good approach.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb Thank you, when I open the calendar the date in txtTime is selected but for some reason, the calendar still opens to the current month. Ex. txtTime is set to 2022/08/01 but the calendar still opens to 2022/09/08 despite 2022/08/01 being highlighted. Do you know whiy that is?

Comment: @ServalChan This is because I did'nt set the `txtTime.Text` in `if (Calendar1.Visible)`. I updated the answer, now you can check.

Comment: @ServalChan please add `page_load` event code in your question for better understanding.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb I added what my page_load looks like. I also updated my code to include your edits. Unfortunately, while the calendar does select the date in txtTime, the month/day shown is still the current one.

Comment: @ServalChan your code looks fine. Did you set the `SelectedDate` attribute inside `aspx` **Designer** file or not? If yes, remove this attribute.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb I checked and the SelectedDate attribute was not used in the aspx Designer file.

Comment: @ServalChan `txtTime.Text` is set only in `Calendar1_SelectionChanged` event. Did you check it cannot be set elsewhere.